# YII2 : Use activeForm and linkPager toghether

Tags: yii2

I would like to use an activeForm and linkPager together.
I mean in the same view, I have defined an activeform with some fields, an sqldataprovider and the showing of the model result (of sqldataprovider). All is nice when I click on the submit button of the activeform.

Now, I would like to add a linkPager by using :

```
echo \yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination'=>$dataProvider->pagination,
]);
```

And when I click and one of buttons of linkpager (to change page), the fields of the activeform are not linked, I mean : the datasqlprovider does not filter with these fields...

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to populate the ActiveForm manually based on the request parameter:

```
$searchModel = new JobSeekerSearch(); // extended from JobSeeker
$params = Yii::$app->request->queryParams; // this is the query string parameter
if( !empty( $params['JobSeekerSearch'] ) ){
    $searchModel->fullName = $params['JobSeekerSearch']['fullName']; // populate your model
}
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search($params); // submit the search parameter to your search model
```

then make sure to create your ActiveForm based on the model(JobSeekerSearch for this example)